# ansible: getting values out of dictsort

Tags: ansible

I have the following dictionary:

```
bigip_provider:
  bigip1: "10.0.0.16"
  bigip2: "10.0.0.18"
  bigip3: "10.0.0.17"
  bigip4: "10.0.0.19"
  bigip5: "10.0.0.27"
  bigip6: "10.0.0.23"
  bigip7: "10.0.0.25"
  bigip8: "10.0.0.28"
```

And I wanted to get the values converting them into a string:

```
{{ bigip_provider.values() | list | join('/24 ') +'/24' }}
```

but with the values sorted by the key: ie {{ bigip_provider | dictsort ... }

I've tried to extract only the values output by dictsort with  map and selectattr but I haven't found a way of doing this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can access list elements with dot-notation (like `mylist.1`), so you can use `map(attribute='1')` to reduce lists (kind of hack, but it's ok):

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    bigip_provider:
      bigip9: "10.0.0.16"
      bigip2: "10.0.0.18"
      bigip3: "10.0.0.17"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ bigip_provider | dictsort | map(attribute='1') | map('regex_replace','$','/24') | list }}"
```

Result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "10.0.0.18/24",
        "10.0.0.17/24",
        "10.0.0.16/24"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Konstantin! :-)

It does the trick! I didn't find any example/doc of map where attribute could specify a position.

Actually I don't find it a hack. It's just perfect for me.